# What is the best practice to log to Logstash from a .Net application?

Tags: .net, performance, logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I did a lot of research, but couldn't get an absolute answer.

I have an ELK stack, and three separate applications (2 Asp.Net WebForms apps & one Windows service app written in C# & C++). All of them use a unified "Infrastructures" .Net assembly which contains a static "Trace" class.
The Trace class holds different writers (HttpLogWriter, FileLogWriter, WindowsEventLogWriter...). It also has methods named "Information", "Debug", "Error" and more which all call a "Log" method implemented in each writer.

We write **A lot** of logs, and I'm not sure what is the best way to write them using the HttpLogWriter.

Currently, HttpLogWriter uses "HttpClient" class to send the log to Logstash.

When I installed Logstash on a weak machine (On AWS), I had some performance issues. Maybe it will be sorted out if I'll use a stronger machine for Logstash, but I don't want my code to rely on it.

What is the best way to do it?

Ideas I had:

- Use 1 thread for the class Trace (How?).
- Use BlockingQueue class.
- Use Fire and Forget pattern (How?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question isn't about *Logstash*. It's about sending lots of messages. *Don't* try to send them synchronously, queue them and send them periodically. Logstash is just a sink/target for whatever logging library you use. Many logging libraries already support asynchronous logging or batching, eg Logary.

Comment: BTW most logging libraries have an HTTP target as well, or provide an ElasticSearch target. No need to write your own. Serilog for example has a [queueing sink for Elastic](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch).  Even if you don't use it, you can check the code and create a similar sink